# How to connect Hardhat to my own private geth chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, hardhat

I can connect truffle to my own geth chain, with this setting

```
$ vi truffle-config.js
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "mydomain.com",
      port: 9000,
      network_id: "*",
    }
  }
```

but hardhat couldn't.

hardhat.config.ts

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
chainId: 2000,
      url:"http://mydomain.com:9000"
      chainId: 2000,
    }
  }
};
```

It's strange.
I run geth with chainid 2000, but hardhat error said it connected to 2020.

> Hardhat was set to use chain id 2000, but connected to a chain with id 2020.

Here's my geth setting.

```
geth --networkid 2000 --nodiscover --datadir data --http --http.port 9000 --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain '*' $ARGS --http.vhosts "*" --nodiscover --allow-insecure-unlock --http.api 'web3,eth,net,debug,personal'
```

```
 npx hardhat run --network localhost  scripts/deploy.js
```

later I changed chainId to 2020, error disappeared but ProviderError:HttpProviderError happend.

Answer (score 0):

## If what you want is to have a local ethereum node only for development (recommended)

You can use the same hardhat. It comes built-in with Hardhat Network, a local Ethereum network node designed for development. It allows you to deploy your contracts, run your tests and debug your code, all within the confines of your local machine.

```bash
npx hardhat run --network hardhat scripts/my-script.js
```

Even with hardhat you can independently run a node so that external clients can connect to it. This could be MetaMask, your Dapp interface, or a script. To run Hardhat Network this way, inside your project run:

```bash
npx hardhat node
```

Then just connect your metamask to http://127.0.0.1:8545 and in the metamask you can load any of the accounts that the hardhat generates for development.

You can read more in the following link: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview

### If you still want to connect hardhat with geth  then you can visit this link

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started#list-accounts